# Missing connections in tomcat jdbc connection pool

Tags: mysql, tomcat, ubuntu, connection-pooling

We just migrated from dbcp to tomcat jdbc connection pooling.
We tried the system in load and received the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [IA1856] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 1 seconds, none available[size:125; busy:90; idle:0; lastwait:1000].
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:632)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:174)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:124)
        at com.inneractive.model.mappings.BasicPersistenceEntityMapping.getConnection(BasicPersistenceEntityMapping.java:233)
        at com.inneractive.model.mappings.BasicPersistenceEntityMapping.callWithConnection(BasicPersistenceEntityMapping.java:243)
        at com.inneractive.model.mappings.PersistenceEntityMapping.get(PersistenceEntityMapping.java:194)
        at com.inneractive.model.data.client.ClientUtils.GetClientByExamples(ClientUtils.java:353)
        at com.inneractive.client.ExternalAdRingsClientStart.getClientInfoByRequestParametersOrInsert(ExternalAdRingsClientStart.java:1329)
        at com.inneractive.client.ExternalAdRingsClientStart.newClientSession(ExternalAdRingsClientStart.java:245)
        at com.inneractive.simpleM2M.web.SimpleM2MProtocolBean.generateCampaign(SimpleM2MProtocolBean.java:235)
        at com.inneractive.simpleM2M.web.SimpleM2MProtocolBean.generateCampaign(SimpleM2MProtocolBean.java:219)
        at com.inneractive.simpleM2M.web.AdsServlet.doGet(AdsServlet.java:175)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:396)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Notice this:

```
[size:125; busy:90; idle:0; lastwait:1000]
```

Where are the connections that are not busy?
The busy number kept going down after this, 
but we still didnt manage to get any connections.

Any ideas?

Configuration:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" loginTimeout="10000"
                maxActive="35" maxIdle="35" maxWait="1000" name="jdbc/mysql"
                password="-----" testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="false" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?elideSetAutoCommits=true&amp;useDynamicCharsetInfo=false&amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;useLocalSessionState=true&amp;useLocalTransactionState=true&amp;alwaysSendSetIsolation=false&amp;cacheServerConfiguration=true&amp;noAccessToProcedureBodies=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
                username="root" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```

env: ubuntu and tomcat 6. db - mysql

Comment: Did you try to increase connection pool size? What happen if you increase the size?

Comment: I cannot increase the number of connections, since I have multiple servers, and I am at the top limit of the database. However, I think this will happen at a larger number..

Comment: We could guess, or you could post your configuration.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz it sounds to me like a JDBC/Tomcat bug, what in the configuration could cause something like that ?

Comment: It is more likely a problem with your environment or configuration. You have posted the details to neither of those. Please do so.

Comment: sorry for not replying sooner. i added my configuration

Comment: @yaelalfasi Any chance you ran into https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53367

Comment: @Andi - not sure, the db seems fine... and there really isn't much data there. not even sure which version has the fix so i can try it. do you know ?

Comment: @yaelalfasi try the latest version of Tomcat. Also you can enabled debug messages for Tomcat and see what's happening..

Comment: Maybe maxWait is too short. Give it at least 5s (5000 ms). Conditioned by environment, response of DB, etc.

Comment: Maybe it's not releasing back connections to the pool. Try to monitor the connections on the mysql side, using the link: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mysql/how-show-open-database-connections-mysql Also increase your maxWait to at least 10000 (default value is 30000, probably for a reason)

Comment: Hi, thanks but i cant set the maxWait any higher, my server must respond in less than a second in average. if there is no connection we rather return a default result than make the user wait. this is the settings we had before the migration from dbcp and it worked.

Comment: we have upgraded to the latest version: tomcat-jdbc 7.0.29 and now it doesn't happen every time but once in a while. which isn't much better. the latest exception was: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [IA1406] -> Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 1 seconds, none available[size:125; busy:123; idle:0; lastwait:840].

Comment: do you have any progress or more information on the issue? thanks.

Comment: Do you have the total incoming connections as a comparison of the server pool versus the jdbc pool quantities?

Comment: this was ages ago but i think the tomcat had 3000 threads

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Taking a look at the source of [ConnectionPool.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tags/JDBC_POOL_1_1_0_1/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.java) you seem to hit this code snippet in the `borrowConnection()` method:

```
        //we didn't get a connection, lets see if we timed out
        if (con == null) {
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - now) >= maxWait) {
                throw new SQLException("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] " +
                    "Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in " + (maxWait / 1000) +
                    " seconds, none available["+busy.size()+" in use].");
            } else {
                //no timeout, lets try again
                continue;
            }
        }
```

So according to this, your connection is **Null**.

The value of `con` is retrieved on the line:

```
PooledConnection con = idle.poll();
```

if you track the code, you will see `idle` is (depending on your configuration, but by default) [FairBlockingQueue](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tags/JDBC_POOL_1_1_0_1/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/FairBlockingQueue.java). You may checkout the implementation for hints.

In general you always have to close ResultSets, Statements, and Connections and used connections should be correctly released back to the pool. 
Not doing so correctly may result in connections never been closed => never being available again for reuse (connection pool "leaks").

I suggest you construct some detailed logging over the state of the pool and monitor it to isolate the problem.

Some guidelines from Apache for preventing database connection pool leaks:

```
removeAbandoned="true"
```

abandoned database connections are removed and recycled

```
removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
```

set the number of seconds a database connection has been idle before it is considered abandoned

```
logAbandoned="true"
```

log a stack trace of the code which abandoned the database connection resources. Keep in mind that "logging of abandoned Connections adds overhead for every Connection borrow because a stack trace has to be generated."

I still think slightly increasing the `maxWait` value (1200, 1500, 1700 - just experiment, there will be no difference in the response times from user perspective) will clear those rare cases, in which you still have problems.

Answer (score 6):

> "where are the connections that are not busy ?"

It sounds like they've been dropped and for some reason your connection pool isn't trying to reconnect them.

Add this to the URL that you're connecting to:

```
autoReconnect=true
```

And add this as a property to the resource should cause dead connections to be reconnected automatically.

```
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
```

Also this should allow you to see connections being dropped:

```
logAbandoned="true"
```

There's multiple similar questions on stack overflow.

[Tomcat connection pooling,idle connections,and connection creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359732/tomcat-connection-pooling-idle-connections-and-connection-creation)
[JDBC Connection pool not reopening Connections in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870288/jdbc-connection-pool-not-reopening-connections-in-tomcat?rq=1)

However it may also be that you're not releasing the connections completely which is the cause of them dying.
[JDBC MySql connection pooling practices to avoid exhausted connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313197/jdbc-mysql-connection-pooling-practices?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

seems to be a bug in the pool, `size` variable is incremented, then trying to create connection,
but if creation fails... we have `size` value large and no actual connections in pool - terrible :

```
    //if we get here, see if we need to create one
    //this is not 100% accurate since it doesn't use a shared
    //atomic variable - a connection can become idle while we are creating
    //a new connection
    if (size.get() < getPoolProperties().getMaxActive()) {
        //atomic duplicate check
        if (size.addAndGet(1) > getPoolProperties().getMaxActive()) {
            //if we got here, two threads passed through the first if
            size.decrementAndGet();
        } else {
            //create a connection, we're below the limit
            return createConnection(now, con, username, password);
        }
    } //end if
```

Comment: `size` is decremented in `createConnection()` if the creation fails, so it *seems* correct, however I do suspect that some race condition causes a wrong value of `size` because I'm getting `PoolExhaustedException` with `size=10, busy=0, idle=0` (the pool is empty so it should try to create a new connection instead of wating for an idle one but it *thinks* it is not empty because of the value of size).